# Circle C.I. force build fail

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, rubocop

I have this pipeline:

```
machine:
  ...

  ruby:
    version:
      2.2.4

database:
  ...

test:
  pre: bundle exec rubocop

deployment:
  production:
    ...
```

Suppose that was a error in my code (found by rubocop). I would like to force the build run. But now Circle C.I. continues and run my specs (unnecessary in this case).

I just want to force failing if rubocop has exited with non-zero.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

CircleCI only continues if each command exits as true. This ensures that the rubocop will exit as true:

```
yaml
test:
  pre: bundle exec rubocop || true
```